# Saving types of templated classes

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, stdtuple

Consider these simplified classes (Interface, and templated Derived class):

```cpp
class Interface
{
    virtual ~Interface() = default;
};

template<typename... T>
class Derived : public Interface
{
    std::tuple<T...> member;
};
```

And then I push arbitrary templated types of Derived class into data vector that holds Interface pointer.

```cpp
std::vector<Interface*> data;
push_back(new Derived<int, float>{});
push_back(new Derived<float, float>{});
push_back(new Derived<double, char>{});
```

My question is how could I get template type from the `Interface*` without knowing what type it is (since I do not know what type it is I also can not cast it to the proper type). Preferably I would like to associate each index of vector with the types used in the template.

I tried storing typedef/alias for each derived class, but I could not find a way to accomplish this. Would that be even possible to achieve, since classes/types are compile time concept?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to know the types? What do you want to do with them?

Comment: @JHBonarius I would like to cast Interface* to the correct derived class type and the also use those types to create new permutations of Derived class template.

Comment: @bigcheese You are describing a solution to some other problem.  What do you want to do with those produced permutations?  If you say "everything" then the answers you get will suck.  If you restrict it enough, there are good answers.

Answer (score 2):

Template types *exist* only during compile time. You can't get the template type back from `Ìnterface`. But you could create a *runtime type* which represents your type. In C++ RTTI / run time type information support is very limited. But hava a look at [type_index](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index).